# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'view'

Tags: python, django

[My filetree looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIdPm.png)

So in my urls.py folder, I have the following code:

```
from django.urls import path
from view import views
#URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)

]
```

The error I get when I am trying to python manage.py runserver is

File "/Users/swathikumar/Desktop/storefront/playground/urls.py", line 3, in 
from view import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'view'

View is a folder I created which has both **init**.py file and views.py file which has the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
# request -> response
# request handler
# action
def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World.')
```

I do not know how to solve this error of resolving the import of views into urls.py. All these files are in a playground app folder.

I was expecting my serevr to give me Hello World upon entering the http request.

Comment: Show us your full file structure layout.  Also show us the value of INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`.

Comment: Read an introductory Django tutorial before attempting to start a Django project. You should have used the `startapp` management command to create the app, then added it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also `view` is not a good name for an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the views from the current folder so you can access the current folder with dot(.) For example:

from . import models

from . import views

You can try this code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

#URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the app is `playground`, if I read that correctly, so you import this with:

```
#       🖟 name of the app
from playground import views
```

Comment: If I do that I get another error saying No module such as playground found

Comment: @SwathiKumar: can you provide the filetree? Based on the traceback, the `urls.py` is in `playground/urls.py`?

Comment: I have added the file tree into the initial description, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
#URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `view` is a sub-module in the current module `playground`, you can import it as follows:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .view import views # added dot in front of module to indicate current directory.
# URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)

]
```

Or better yet

```
from django.urls import path
from playground.view import views
# URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)

]
```